# ¿Se puede elegir un pixel de una imagen con el ratón?

Tags: python, imagen

Estoy tratando de crear un programa en PYTHON que me permita escoger uno ( o varios) pixeles de una imagen. Quiero que el usuario del programa lo elija con el raton en la misma imagen. ¿Es posible hacerlo?
Gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: "Si se puede." Esto sería una respuesta válida a tu pregunta, prueba a investigar un poco, a empezar con el desarrollo y una vez que lo tengas algo mas avanzado, regresa con un problema específico: "Al pasarle las coordenadas de la imagen siempre me recoge las coordenadas 0,0". Mas información en: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido lo que deseaba con el programa, sin embargo, no se como hacer para que espere a que el usuario clicke el pixel, en vez de seleccionar directamente donde está al compilarlo. Gracias por vuestro tiempo.

```
import keyboard
import pyautogui
import os

copyPixeltoClipboard = True
copyColortoClipboard = True

def addToClipBoard(text):
    command = 'echo ' + text.strip() + '| clip'
    os.system(command)


x = pyautogui.position()[0]
y = pyautogui.position()[1]

if copyColortoClipboard:
                addToClipBoard(str(pyautogui.pixel(x,y)))

print (pyautogui.pixel(x,y))
```